# Periodically send data from one mongodb server to another

Tags: mongodb

I ran into a situation that obliged me to periodically(let's say everyday) copy all data stored in my mongodb production server into another remote server.
The export process must be done in such a way that a function stored in the production server runs periodically and sends data to the second server...
I tried the copydb command but the issue with this command is that it's useful for importing data and not exporting data

> db.runCommand({copydb: 1, fromdb: "db", todb: "db",
>   fromhost: "production_host"})

Comment: do you need to run the script from inside mongoshell? or could it be run on the OS?

Comment: I need it to run from mongo shell not the system cmd

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `db.runCommand`, you need to use `db.copyDatabase`.

```
db.copyDatabase(fromdb, todb, fromhost, username, password, mechanism)
```

you can find a detailed reference on how to use the command here - https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/

Comment: It's the same and for my case, I need to export a database not to import it.. Like if i need a copyDatabase having one extra param which is the "tohost"